# Moving data frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Please see below the dataset that I am using for my analyses. HI would like to move `2:25` after col `145`.

structure(list(Duration = c(10, 20), `00:00` = c(0, 0), `00:10` = c(0,
0), `00:20` = c(0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 0), `00:40` = c(0.04, 0.00173913
), `00:50` = c(0, 0.008695652), `01:00` = c(0, 0), `01:10` = c(0,
0), `01:20` = c(0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 0), `01:40` = c(0, 0),
`01:50` = c(0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 0), `02:10` = c(0, 0),
`02:20` = c(0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 0), `02:40` = c(0, 0),
`02:50` = c(0, 0), `03:00` = c(0.00173913, 0), `03:10` = c(0,
0), `03:20` = c(0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 0), `03:40` = c(0.005217391,
0.00173913), `03:50` = c(0.00173913, 0), `04:00` = c(0, 0
), `04:10` = c(0.003478261, 0), `04:20` = c(0, 0), `04:30` = c(0.00173913,
0.00173913), `04:40` = c(0, 0.005217391), `04:50` = c(0.005217391,
0), `05:00` = c(0, 0), `05:10` = c(0, 0), `05:20` = c(0,
0), `05:30` = c(0, 0), `05:40` = c(0, 0), `05:50` = c(0,
0), `06:00` = c(0.00173913, 0), `06:10` = c(0, 0.00173913
), `06:20` = c(0.00173913, 0), `06:30` = c(0.005217391, 0
), `06:40` = c(0.003478261, 0.00173913), `06:50` = c(0.00173913,
0.00173913), `07:00` = c(0, 0), `07:10` = c(0.005217391,
0), `07:20` = c(0.003478261, 0), `07:30` = c(0.003478261,
0.00173913), `07:40` = c(0.00173913, 0.00173913), `07:50` = c(0,
0), `08:00` = c(0.003478261, 0), `08:10` = c(0.00173913,
0), `08:20` = c(0.005217391, 0), `08:30` = c(0, 0), `08:40` = c(0,
0.00173913), `08:50` = c(0.003478261, 0), `09:00` = c(0.013913043,
0), `09:10` = c(0.006956522, 0), `09:20` = c(0, 0), `09:30` = c(0.003478261,
0), `09:40` = c(0, 0), `09:50` = c(0, 0.00173913), `10:00` = c(0.00173913,
0.00173913), `10:10` = c(0.005217391, 0.00173913), `10:20` = c(0.00173913,
0.00173913), `10:30` = c(0.00173913, 0.00173913), `10:40` = c(0.00173913,
0), `10:50` = c(0, 0.00173913), `11:00` = c(0.00173913, 0
), `11:10` = c(0.006956522, 0.00173913), `11:20` = c(0, 0
), `11:30` = c(0, 0), `11:40` = c(0, 0), `11:50` = c(0, 0
), `12:00` = c(0.003478261, 0), `12:10` = c(0.003478261,
0), `12:20` = c(0, 0), `12:30` = c(0.00173913, 0), `12:40` = c(0.00173913,
0), `12:50` = c(0, 0), `13:00` = c(0, 0), `13:10` = c(0.005217391,
0), `13:20` = c(0, 0), `13:30` = c(0, 0.00173913), `13:40` = c(0,
0), `13:50` = c(0.005217391, 0.00173913), `14:00` = c(0.003478261,
0.00173913), `14:10` = c(0.00173913, 0), `14:20` = c(0.005217391,
0), `14:30` = c(0.00173913, 0.00173913), `14:40` = c(0.003478261,
0), `14:50` = c(0.00173913, 0), `15:00` = c(0, 0), `15:10` = c(0.005217391,
0.00173913), `15:20` = c(0, 0.00173913), `15:30` = c(0.006956522,
0), `15:40` = c(0.008695652, 0.00173913), `15:50` = c(0.003478261,
0), `16:00` = c(0.00173913, 0), `16:10` = c(0.00173913, 0
), `16:20` = c(0.003478261, 0.00173913), `16:30` = c(0.00173913,
0), `16:40` = c(0.00173913, 0.00173913), `16:50` = c(0.005217391,
0.006956522), `17:00` = c(0.003478261, 0.00173913), `17:10` = c(0.017391304,
0), `17:20` = c(0.005217391, 0.005217391), `17:30` = c(0.005217391,
0.00173913), `17:40` = c(0.005217391, 0.00173913), `17:50` = c(0.00173913,
0.003478261), `18:00` = c(0.00173913, 0.00173913), `18:10` = c(0.010434783,
0.00173913), `18:20` = c(0.00173913, 0), `18:30` = c(0.00173913,
0.003478261), `18:40` = c(0.00173913, 0), `18:50` = c(0.00173913,
0), `19:00` = c(0.00173913, 0.00173913), `19:10` = c(0.006956522,
0), `19:20` = c(0.005217391, 0.003478261), `19:30` = c(0,
0), `19:40` = c(0, 0), `19:50` = c(0, 0.003478261), `20:00` = c(0.008695652,
0), `20:10` = c(0.006956522, 0.003478261), `20:20` = c(0.003478261,
0), `20:30` = c(0, 0), `20:40` = c(0.008695652, 0), `20:50` = c(0,
0), `21:00` = c(0.00173913, 0), `21:10` = c(0.00173913, 0
), `21:20` = c(0, 0), `21:30` = c(0, 0), `21:40` = c(0, 0
), `21:50` = c(0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 0), `22:10` = c(0, 0
), `22:20` = c(0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 0), `22:40` = c(0, 0
), `22:50` = c(0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 0), `23:10` = c(0, 0
), `23:20` = c(0, 0), `23:30` = c(0, 0), `23:40` = c(0, 0
), `23:50` = c(0, 0)), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
Duration = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `00:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `00:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `00:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `00:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `00:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `00:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `01:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `01:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `01:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `01:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `01:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `01:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `02:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `02:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `02:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `02:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `02:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `02:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `03:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `03:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `03:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `03:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `03:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `03:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `04:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `04:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `04:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `04:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `04:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `04:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `05:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `05:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `05:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `05:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `05:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `05:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `06:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `06:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `06:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `06:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `06:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `06:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `07:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `07:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `07:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `07:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `07:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `07:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `08:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `08:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `08:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `08:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `08:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `08:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `09:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `09:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `09:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `09:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `09:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `09:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `10:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `10:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `10:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `10:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `10:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `10:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `11:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `11:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `11:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `11:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `11:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `11:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `12:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `12:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `12:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `12:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `12:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `12:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `13:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `13:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `13:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `13:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `13:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `13:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `14:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `14:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `14:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `14:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `14:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `14:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `15:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `15:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `15:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `15:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `15:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `15:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `16:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `16:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `16:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `16:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `16:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `16:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `17:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `17:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `17:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `17:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `17:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `17:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `18:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `18:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `18:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `18:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `18:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `18:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `19:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `19:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `19:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `19:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `19:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `19:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `20:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `20:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `20:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `20:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `20:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `20:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `21:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `21:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `21:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `21:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `21:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `21:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `22:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `22:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `22:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `22:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `22:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `22:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `23:00` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `23:10` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `23:20` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `23:30` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `23:40` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector")), `23:50` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess",
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

Comment: do you want to rename columns or do you want to rearrange the columns (changing the order of columns)? not sure what you mean with 'delete the empty space'

Comment: @peter rearrange order, thanks; I just don't want to have any empty space between column 1 and column 26 after moving 2:25 to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
cbind(df[, -2:-25], df[, 2:25])
```

Comment: But  whatif the dataframe has more than 145 columns? this would not ensure the right order or does it? This simply binds the block of columns to the end of the df, not necessarily after 145.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I rely on an assumption that the dataframe cannot have more than 145 columns because one day only has 24 * 60 = 1440 minutes or 144 10-minute time intervals. One extra is for the column `Duration`. I will upvote your solution.

Answer (score 2):

This should be more robust. Meaning it would produce the same results even when the number of columns change (especially when it grows):

```
df_new <- cbind(df[, 1:145], df[, 2:25], df[, 146:ncol(df)]) # move a duplicate of the columns in the right position
df_new <- df_new[, -2:-25] # delete columns from original positions
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution

```r
library(dplyr)
relocate(df, 2:25, .after = 145)
```

Almost reads exactly like your question :)

To generically move them to the end of the columns no matter how many columns

```r
df %>% relocate(2:25, .after = last_col())
```